# How to find out if a question exists or not on this site

Tags: discussion, search

What is a good way to find a question about the issue that I wish to ask about exists on this site?

Because when I'm going to ask, first I search. If I find, OK, but sometimes I don't find and when I ask about the issue I get downvoted, because that question is duplicate. Is there a way to find out if my issue already was asked? And how be sure if the issue found matches with my search?

Comment: Use google for searching. The results are way better than the internal search engine. Add "Stack Overflow" to your google search queries.

Comment: @user0042, ok. Thanks for response me. I need to ask because i have a issue, but i was ban in this site, so i need to make a good question, the question and i don't come back to the ban. Really i'm fear to ask and receive downvote, my reputation is low.

Comment: Did you consider following [this guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)?

Comment: Like [this](https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Ahttps%3A%2F%2Fmeta.stackoverflow.com+how+to+best+search+stackoverflow)

Comment: @user0042: better to add: `site:https://stackoverflow.com/` to your Google search

Comment: Thanks for all. @user0042 I'm reading your tip and as of now i'll search for the google before to ask.

Comment: @Hover THX, for that. I didn't know that google supports that syntax.

Comment: Does anyone else chuckle at the irony that this question got closed as a duplicate?